# How to find if some activity is on stack ( just to call finish() ) or not on stack?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have app with lot off activities and user can walk between activities. How to find if some activity is on stack ( just to call finish() ) or not on stack ?

Comment: Can you provide a better example for why you'd want to find an activity to close it? I can't think of a reason you'd want to go and close an activity that is somewhere random on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

you need to be a little more clearer about what you are looking for.

this class can be used to know the state of running processes.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html

also adding on your AndroidManifest.xml the activity as SingleInstace
(Application->Activity->Launch mode->SingleInstance).
If your activity is running, it wont create a new one.

using this will help you clear off all the top activities called before A in your app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve a list of active tasks (and components participating in each task) like this:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
    ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
    ...
}
```

However, this requires you to ask for the `android.permission.GET_TASKS` permission in AndroidManifest.